# Typescript complains about discriminated union types when there is no type annotation

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

It seems to me that typescript does not recognise discriminated union types when provided without any type annotation. Am I missing something ? Is there some reason for that ?

```js
export type Stuff = AType | BType

export type AType = { status: Kind.A; name: string }

export type BType = { status: Kind.B; quantity: number }

export enum Kind {
  A,
  B,
}

function PlayWithStuff(stuff: Stuff) {
  console.log('some stuff', stuff)
}

const stuff = {
  status: Kind.B,
  quantity: 2,
}

PlayWithStuff(stuff)
//            ^^^^^
// Argument of type '{ status: Kind; quantity: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stuff'.
//   Type '{ status: Kind; quantity: number; }' is not assignable to type 'BType'.
//     Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
//       Type 'Kind' is not assignable to type 'Kind.B'.

const secondStuff: Stuff = {
  status: Kind.B,
  quantity: 2,
}

PlayWithStuff(secondStuff)
// OK, the type annotation on `secondStuff` fixes the problem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When initializing object literals, Typescript will infer property types, but not as constants, since they are not readonly.

So the type of `stuff` will be `{ status: Kind, quantity: number }`, because you can later change it to:

```
const stuff = {
    status: Kind.B,
    quantity: 2,
};

stuff.status = Kind.A;
```

So now it's not assignable to `BType` (nor AType for that matter).

You can use `as const`:

```
const stuff = {
    status: Kind.B,
    quantity: 2,
} as const;
```

Now the type is inferred as `{ readonly status: Kind.B, readonly quantity: 2}` which is always assignable to BType.

Or you could do what you did and just give it type annotation:

```
const stuff: BType = {
    status: Kind.B,
    quantity: 2,
};

stuff.status = Kind.A; // Errors
```